# Multi token Arbitrage Bot for Dexes

Tags: tokens, ether, uniswap, pancakeswap, sushiswap

I was thinking of making a program to find & execute arbitrage.
Say we have a 100 token A which we can swap back & forth with  4 other tokens to end up making a profit by combining it with flash loans. How can I do this?

It will check all possible combinations like this. Afer each swap it will check back if the balance of B token will be increased or not if we swap from that point.

```sh
B->A->C->D->E
B->A->C->E->D
B->A->D->C->E
B->A->D->E->C
B->A->E->C->D
B->A->E->D->C
B->C->A->D->E
B->C->A->E->D
B->C->D->A->E
B->C->D->E->A
B->C->E->A->D
B->C->E->D->A
B->D->A->C->E
B->D->A->E->C
B->D->C->A->E
B->D->C->E->A
B->D->E->A->C
B->D->E->C->A
B->E->A->C->D
B->E->A->D->C
B->E->C->A->D
B->E->C->D->A
B->E->D->A->C
B->E->D->C->A
```

I don't know whether it's possible or not just want to have some discussion with people who has more knowledge than me.

Comment: Hi Saikat, it's certainly possible, but Stack Exchange is not a discussion site. The QA format expected here is specific question -> specific answer. You might want to start by reading existing research on DEX arbitrage, there are some academic papers. Paradigm's Artemis could help when you get to implementing it.